# Amazon CognitoIdentityServiceProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I did a complete server side cognito user signup,forgot password, change password etc.
        http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

I didn't get a solution to userpool username password verification in backend or Lambda function

I'll give my reference below

```
https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth/blob/master/www/changePassword.html
```

Description : This url give client side authentication and JWT token password verification through server side

Expection:

- Client side doesn't need to signin signup, request to all process expect in server side or lambda function
- Should not use Lambda invoke function in client side, we are expecting, Ajax call -> Api Gateway ->Lambda function -> Cognito process

  https://github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/Identity-Code/tree/master/assets/js

My Expection:

This [Amazon CognitoIdentityServiceProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html) Page give all Cognito process in server side or lambda function,  But they not provide username password verification/Authentication,

Kindly please provide solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question but what language are you trying to use? With Cognito, we have examples for Android, Javascript, iOS